# Trying to receive incoming UDP packets, empty buffer

Tags: c++, udp

I'm trying to read these incoming UDP packets using Wireshark:

[image: Wireshark]

I'm using the next code:

```
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
struct sockaddr_in remaddr;     /* remote address */
int  slen = sizeof(remaddr);

int s, recvlen;
char buf[BUFLEN];
char message[BUFLEN];
WSADATA wsa;

//Initialise winsock
printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
{
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("Initialised.\n");


//create socket
if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR) //IPPROTO_UDP
{
    printf("socket() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//setup address structure
memset((char *)&si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);

if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&si_other, sizeof(si_other)) < 0) {
    perror("bind failed");
    return 0;
}

u_long nMode = 1; // 1: NON-BLOCKING
if (ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &nMode) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
//start communication
while (1)
{

    printf("waiting on port %d\n", PORT);

    if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("recvfrom() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Done");
    puts(buf);
}
```

The address I'm binding is 192.168.1.1 and the port 1234.

And the given output by WSAGetLastError is an empty buffer error: 10035

I tried to disconnect firewall, antivirus...and I'm running the program as a administrator, and it didn't help.

Why is the buffer empty? I'm clearly seeing that there are packets coming, what could be blocking the incoming data to the socket?

Comment: Why non-blocking?

Comment: Because with non-blocking I'am able to to read the error and see that the buffer is empty, otherwise  the program halts on recvfrom function...

Comment: But if it's non-blocking the call might return simply because there is no data available yet.  What is the error -- `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`?

Comment: What is the IP of your computer ? Usually .1 will be the gateway or router.

Comment: The IP 192.168.1.1 is shown as a gateway at the IP config. also is the one which is receiving the packages (please see the above wireshark picture)...I tried INADDR_ANY and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

> the given output by `WSAGetLastError()` is an empty buffer error: 10035

No it isn't. 10035 is `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`. That means the operation would block in blocking mode, i.e. that no data was present to be received at the moment you called `recvfrom()`.

> The address I'm binding is 192.168.1.1
>
> The IP 192.168.1.1 is shown as a gateway

These two statements are mutually inconsistent. If it's a gateway it's an external IP address, and if it's an external IP address you can't bind to it.

> I tried INADDR_ANY and it didn't help

Not surprising. If you're not 192.168.1.1 you can't receive its messages. Unclear why you would think otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As @EJP mentioned 10035 is `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, i.e., no data is ready. The cause of this is that the receiver is 192.168.1.1 which is your gateway's IP address, thus not a local IP. In this case you cannot receive the packets in a normal manner.

You can receive these packets, even though they are not meant for you, by using an UDP sniffer, e.g., using [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/).

Comment: Many thanks Jonas that clarify why I can't receive these packages. Thanks for the link I'll have a look.

Comment: @joe You're most welcome. Let me know if you need further assistance, e.g., using libpcap or writing your own packet capture function. Please accept (and possibly upvote) an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answers, they pointed me to the right direction. I 've got now the program working and I'm able to receive the incoming UDP packets.

The solution was to "sniff" these UDP packets, winsock allows that using the  WSAIoctl function after bind, in my case adding the next code to the above program (after the bind function):

```
if (WSAIoctl(s, SIO_RCVALL, &j, sizeof(j), 0, 0, (LPDWORD)&si_other, 0, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("WSAIoctl() failed.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

I hope could help somebody else with similar issue.

Comment: The solution was to not bind to an external IP address. And the word is packets, not packages.